# ASP.NET MVC - Refused to execute script from site because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: debugging, model-view-controller, bundling-and-minification, esapi, mime-message

Bundling is not rendering the .js file names properly post hosting the site in production.

**Bundle Config File**

```
       // esapi4js dependencies
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/esapi4js").Include(
            "~/Scripts/esapi4js/lib/log4js.js",
            // esapi4js core
            "~/Scripts/esapi4js/esapi.js",
            // esapi4js i18n resources
            "~/Scripts/esapi4js/resources/i18n/ESAPI_Standard_en_US.properties.js",
            // esapi4js configuration
            "~/Scripts/esapi4js/resources/Base.esapi.properties.js"
        ));
```

**Rendering in View**

> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/LayoutJs")

Development script files are being generating successfully. But in production MIME type check issue is being generating.

**Issue in browser console**

> Refused to execute script from 'https://sitename.com/esapi4js?v=RtsocsadePaadEQ9_ZYYh7lodAovrehjkHWnqm6xSaw1' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.